# What is difference between aws redshift-data permissions and redshift permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, identity-management

Basically, I am trying to add permissions for AWS redshift. But AWS provides permissions under two headings, that is, redshift and redshift-data.

For example, if I want to have permissions of ListDatabases, then aws provides two permissions, one is redshift:ListDatabases and another is redshift-data:ListDatabases, not sure which one I should use.

Somewhere I read that redshift gives access for "Amazon Redshift console" and "redshift-data" gives access for "Cluster". Not sure what does that mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain the differene, lets consider the SDK clients. Notice two clients:

- RedshiftClient
- RedshiftDataClient

The **RedshiftClient** lets you manage Amazon Redshift clusters such as creating clusters, deleting clusters and so on.

The **RedshiftDataClient** lets you perform CRUD operations on the database. For example, insert operations using the **executeStatement** method.

That is the main difference. One lets you manage clusters and the other lets you perform CRUD operations.